# How object scope will work in Angular outside of directives

Tags: angular

I have a popup in Angular and it is using for Delete confirmation.How to pass the object to popup `<div>`.

**Sample Code:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let **user** of users">
   <td style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
      <button (click)="showDeleteConfirm()">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
      </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Need the above user to pass here:**

```
<div class="popupDelete">
   <popup #popupDelete (confirmClick)="ConfirmDelete(**user**)">
      Are you sure, you want to delete this user?
      <br>
   </popup>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `popupDelete` is not a child of your `tr` you'll need to use the controller for this.

In your HTML, notice the parameter to `showDeleteConfirm` and the lack of parameter in `ConfirmDelete`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
   <td style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
                <button (click)="showDeleteConfirm(user)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
            </button>
            </td>
</tr>

<div class="popupDelete">
    <popup #popupDelete (confirmClick)="ConfirmDelete()">
        Are you sure, you want to delete this user?
        <br>
    </popup>

</div>
```

In your TS:

```
public showDeleteConfirm(user)
{
    this.userToDelete = user;
    ...
}

public ConfirmDelete()
{
   Database.Delete.This.User(this.userToDelete);
}
```

If your `popupDelete` were a child of your `tr`, you could pass to `ConfirmDelete` the same `user` that your `*ngFor` introduces. You would end up with multiple `popupDelete` though.